# Cinemachine Third person shooter multiple cameras with different positions not pointing toward same spot

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, game-development, cinemachine

Im doing a third person shooter using Cinemachine package. Now I have 3 cameras, one for view from behind of character, one for over shoulder view and one for sniper scope zoom. Each camera has different offset. This offset is causing cameras to aim at different points. Thing is, I know that changing offset only on forward axis, would fix this issue, but then all the cameras, have to be on same X,Y position, which is not what I want. I saw many TPS games are having their camera pointing same spot regardless of current camera position.
All the cameras are focused on same follow transform and all are using 3rd person follow.
Is there any solution by code, or by using proper cinemachine camera's setup to force cameras always point same spot independent of current camera position?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why cant you have an empty gameobject that is the target for each of the cameras so they all point at the same place

Comment: Yeah i tried to do that. Follow target is object placed under my character which i rotate(called CameraTarget) and lookat target is empty object(let's call this AimTarget) you mentioned. I did set camera Aim as HardLookAt. There is an problem in positioning AimTarget, when AimTarget is child of CameraTarget, camera is rotating around AimTarget, focusing more on this than on CameraTarget.